# Not possible to pass multiple files per commit per GitHub API?

Tags: java, git, api, github

I already use the GitHub API to make automated commits.
For this I'm using a [Java Library from Kohsuke](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api)
It works with this [API command](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file):

```
Create a file
This method creates a new file in a repository
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

But is it possible to include multiple files in 1 Commit per GitHub API?

Comment: Hello Ernst, have you solved in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippit will allow you to prepare a commit with multiple files, then associate a new branch to it, using the [Java library from Kohsuke](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api)

```
// start with a Repository ref
GHRepository repo = ...

// get a sha to represent the root branch to start your commit from.  
// this can come from any number of classes:
//   GHBranch, GHCommit, GHTree, etc...

// for this example, we'll start from the master branch
GHBranch masterBranch = repo.getBranch("master");

// get a tree builder object to build up into the commit. 
// the base of the tree will be the master branch
GHTreeBuilder treeBuilder = repo.createTree().baseTree(masterBranch.getSHA1());

// add entries to the tree in various ways.  
// the nice thing about GHTreeBuilder.textEntry() is that it is an "upsert" (create new or update existing)
treeBuilder = treeBuilder.textEntry(pathToFile, contentOfFile, executable);

// repeat calls of treeBuider.textEntry() or .shaEntry() or .entry() ....

// perform the commit
GHCommit commit = repo.createCommit()
  // base the commit on the tree we built
  .tree(treeBuilder.create().getSha())
  // set the parent of the commit as the master branch
  .parent(masterBranch.getSHA1()).message("multi-file commit").create();

// create a new branch from that commit
String newBranchName = "myNewBranchName";
GHRef newRef = repo.createRef("/refs/heads/" + newBranchName, commit.getSHA1();
GHBranch newBranch = repo.getBranch(newBranchName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Dan Dowma's answer, it is possible to push these changes to an existing branch

```
final String branchName = "main";

// start with a Repository ref
GHRepository repo = ...

// get a sha to represent the root branch to start your commit from.  
// this can come from any number of classes:
//   GHBranch, GHCommit, GHTree, etc...

// for this example, we'll start from the selected branch
GHBranch selectedBranch = repo.getBranch(branchName);

// get a tree builder object to build up into the commit. 
// the base of the tree will be the master branch
GHTreeBuilder treeBuilder = repo.createTree().baseTree(selectedBranch.getSHA1());

// add entries to the tree.
treeBuilder = treeBuilder.add(pathToFile, contentOfFile, executable);

// perform the commit
GHCommit commit = repo.createCommit()
  // base the commit on the tree we built
  .tree(treeBuilder.create().getSha())
  // set the parent of the commit as the master branch
  .parent(selectedBranch.getSHA1()).message("multi-file commit").create();

// Update an existing branch from that commit
GHRef existingBranchRef = repo.getRef("/refs/heads/" + branchName);
existingBranchRef.updateTo(commit.getSHA1());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, maybe a little bit more description would help, but take a look at this:
https://developer.github.com/v3/git/

Comment: What kind of more description do you want? What do you miss?

Comment: Got confused with including multiple files and the API command given, you wish to create multiple files in the repo or update multiple files in the repo or both?

Comment: I want to do both. Right now I have the probably that every file is just 1 commit. Which make it hard when I have a lot of icons. Making one commit per icon upload doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If that is the issue you can do so using the API in the link I posted, notice the API works with the raw git objects and therefore you are able to perform any git function. Including staging and committing multiple files. this should be done using the tree object. An excellent explanation of how this object works and how you can achieve the steps to perform the commit is placed on pro git book.

Comment: Of course, when I posted the link I was not sure what the issue was exactly. I can edit the answer as soon as I have time.

Comment: A little more description indeed - this Gist example, though in JS, is more or less easy to follow and explains what is sent in which order: https://gist.github.com/StephanHoyer/91d8175507fcae8fb31a