# hub4j github-api - Set/Get Local repository root?

Tags: java, github

Where exactly is the root set when you fetch a repo through hub4j's github-api? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56295800/1959534) example that detailed how you could add files from local however I'm not able to get it working, guessing it's because the root is located somewhere else compared to the test file I'm trying to upload. So my question, how can I see/set the local root when creating/fetching repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue, it was twofold:

1. When adding stuff to the treeBuilder the path isn't the path to the file on your disk but the path that it should be in the github repository
2. You need to call on the updateTo(commitSHA) for it to register correctly on Gitub